# pylint: Class 'message' has no 'startswith' member

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint

For some reason, [`pylint`](https://www.pylint.org/) 1.6.4 (astroid 1.4.9) does not like this:

```
try:
    some_package.their_function()
except Exception as ex:
    if ex.message.startswith(...):
        ...
```

It complains:

```
error (E1101, no-member, feed_sentiment) Class 'message' has no 'startswith' member
```

I find this surprising because:

```
>>> type(Exception("foo").message)
<type 'str'>
>>> Exception("foo").message.startswith
<built-in method startswith of str object at 0x10520d360>
```

I think this is a [bug in `pylint`](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1307).

**However, am *I* doing something wrong? What is the "pythonic" way here?**

PS. Yes, I know that the right way is to define my own exception subclass, but I have no control over `some_package`.

PPS. Yes, I know I can annotate the code with `pylint: disable=no-member`.

Comment: Can you include pylint / astroid version?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski: edited (pylint 1.6.4, 
astroid 1.4.9
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 19 2016, 08:29:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)])

Comment: By the way: `message` is deprecated (since python2.6). You can simply use `message = str(ex)` (or `unicode(ex)`) to achieve the same thing (`message =ex.args[0]` avoids error when mixing unicode/str in python2.x).

Comment: @Bakuriu: so you concur with the MSeifert's answer, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pythonic way would be to convert the `ex` to a `str` explicitly because that also converts the message to a string:

```
try:
    some_package.their_function()
except Exception as ex:
    if str(ex).startswith(...):  # or "if something in str(ex)":
```

The problem with `Exception.message` is that it may not be a `str`:

```
>>> try:
...     raise ValueError(1.2)
... except Exception as ex:
...     print ex
...     print type(ex.message)
...     print repr(str(ex))  # force it to be a string
...     print hasattr(ex.message, 'startswith')
ValueError(1.2,)
<type 'float'>
'1.2'
False
```

It's good style and highly advisable that you use `str`s as message but that is by no means guaranteed!

Comment: I've made the point a bit clearer that `Exception.message` might not be a string at all (so it may not have a `startswith` method). No reason to downvote!

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug in `astroid` - a `pylint`'s internal library used for building abstract syntax trees and value inference.

```
import astroid

node = astroid.builder.parse("""
    ex = Exception()
    msg = ex.message
""")
print list(node.locals['msg'][0].infer())
```

Output from this code snippet is:

```
[<ClassDef(message) l.0 [exceptions] at 0x34aadd0>, <ClassDef(message) l.0 [exceptions] at 0x3482cb0>]
```

Output means that `message` attribute on exception instance is inferred as custom class definition, and not string instance.

Thanks for submitting a bug!

Comment: thanks! do I have to move my bug report to the `astroid` package?

Comment: @sds we'll take care about it internally ;) . Once again thanks for a issue ticket.

Comment: I'm not really sure it's a Bug, because there is no guarantee in Python that forces `message` to be a string (see my answer, I guess you downvoted). If you (or pylint) is able to infer that it **must** be a string then it could be a bit buggy but the lack of guarantee is definetly a drawback.